# What is causing this compile error with java Generics and reflection?

Tags: java, generics, reflection

I have a Generic method that should work similarly to recursion, but calling different instances of the method for each calling.

```
public <M extends A> void doSomething(Class<M> mClass, M mObject)
{
    // ... Do something with mObject.

    A object = getObject();
    Class<? extends A> objectClass = object.getClass();

    doSomething(objectClass, objectClass.cast(object)); // Does not compile.
}

private A getObject() {...}
```

The problem is the line with a comment does not compile, giving the following error:

> The method doSomething(Class, M) in the type MainTest is not applicable for the arguments (Class, capture#3-of ? extends A)

I don't quite understand why the compiler does not compile if it can call `doSomething` with M = "? extends A".

Why doesn't it compile?

Comment: Generics please. There are no templates in Java.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The language does not track wildcards like that (it seems). What you need to do is to capture that wildcard, which can be done with a method call with type inference.

```
public <M extends A> void doSomething(Class<M> mClass, M mObject) {
    // ... Do something with mObject.

    A object = getObject();
    Class<? extends A> objectClass = object.getClass();
    privateSomething(objectClass, object);
}
private <T extends A> void privateSomething(Class<T> objectClass, A object) {
    doSomething(objectClass, objectClass.cast(object)); // Should compile.
}
```

As always, whilst reflection has some uses, it's usually a sign of confusion.

Answer (score 4):

Ok here is a crude explanation

You've typed your method so that it will accept M which is a subtype of A

Now you are calling your method using 'objectClass' which is a subtype of A **BUT not necessarily a subtype of M.**

Hence the compiler is complaining...

If you can explain what you are trying to do a bit more, I can help with a solution.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. But why the compiler didn't instantiate another 'doSomething' method, then? It's a generic method.

Comment: It would've worked pre Java 1.5 but post Java 1.5 the compiler cannot find a matching method signature for the call...

Comment: @LeonardoRaele You are making the same mistake you made in your title. This is Generics, not templates. The compiler doesn't 'instantiate' anything in Generics. You are still thinking of templates. Templates is a way of generating new types: Generics is a way of restricting existing types.

Answer (score 1):

When you are asking the compiler to perform a cast, the exact type to perform the cast must be known.  It is not sufficient to tell the compiler that you don't know about the exact type excerpt that it's a subclass of A.

Class tell the compiler that the type of the object is a subclass of A but it doesn't tell the compilator the exact type to be used for the casting.

Your problem is that you are trying to replace Polymorphism with Generic.  As you are learning the hard way, Generic is not the new modern way of doing Polymorphism.